# Passing variable as argument

Tags: python, linux, shell

I have a python script sms.py and it takes two args:

1) a mobile number

2) a random number

The random number is generated by:

`myrandnumber=expr '(' $RANDOM '*' 30  / 32767 ')' + 1`

My sh script looks like this:

```
myrandnumber=`expr '(' $RANDOM '*' 30  / 32767 ')' + 1`

cd /home/janu/programs/

output_filename=output/output-`date +%Y%m%d-%H.%M.%S`.txt
python sms.py -mob 917204785003 --key $myrandnumber > $output_filename
```

I am not able to get the '$myrandnumber' value.

Comment: What doesn't work with this code?

Comment: What is the error? What were you expecting?

Comment: What is the as is outcome and what the to be outcome?

Comment: --key will take a string in the python script.$myrandnumber not accessible. Error : expr: syntax error

Comment: Put `echo RANDOM = $RANDOM` in your script to see if the shell is processing this special variable proerly.

Comment: echo $RANDOM will shows 2344 and echo $myrandnumber shows expr: syntax error

Comment: This works for me, you need to provide more information. Post the full scripts, what environment are you using?

Answer (score 0):

If you made the sms.py script you are beter of using the random lib in the python code:

```
   import random
   key = random.randint(1,3000) # 1 to 3000 inclusive
```